# Error in code saying "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I am following a tutorial on a "Dark Souls"-like game in Unity and I'm getting the error:

> Assets\PlayerLocomotion.cs(76,58): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Transform' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'.

This is my code:

```cs
private void HandleRotation(float delta)
{
    Vector3 targetDir = Vector3.zero;
    float moveOverride = inputHandler.moveAmount;

    targetDir = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
    targetDir += cameraObject.right * inputHandler.horizontal;

    targetDir.Normalize();
    targetDir.y = 0;

    if (targetDir == Vector3.zero)
        targetDir = myTransform.forward;

    float rs = rotationSpeed;

    Quaternion tr = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDir);
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform, tr, rs * delta);

    myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

Comment: Well you can't ... It should probably rather be `Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation), tr, rs * delta` and I would close this as typo-based ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) takes in a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) as an overload (in the first parameter) but you're passing in a Transform. I'm guessing you want to use `myTransform.rotation` instead of the `myTransform` itself.

Comment: Thank you ANF-Studios. That fixed the problem

Comment: Glad I could help.